# Returning the related field using in views.py Django

Tags: django, django-select-related

I have the following code:

## models.py

```
class Model_ItemName(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50) # e.g. "Power Ranger"

class Model_Cart(models.Model):
    item_name = models.ForeignKey(Model_ItemName)
```

## views.py

```
Model_Cart.objects.select_related("item_name").values("item_name")[0]["item_name"] # <---- Expect to return "Power Ranger"
```

My goal is to retrieve the value of the "item_name" (say "Power Ranger") from the Model_ItemName.

I was referring to [this post](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for the solution, but my existing code returns the id number of that "item_name" instead. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `item_name__item_name` as field name (check [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) of documentation for details):

```
Model_Cart.objects.values("item_name__item_name")[0]["item_name__item_name"]
```

Note you don't need select_related in this case, with `values()` Django will fetch `item_name__item_name` with one query using sql join.

Comment: You have just simplifying the existing code. Thank you very much for being a savior. Spent hours dealing with this.